# Can we upgrade Cardinal SDK present in braintreepayments:drop-in manually in ANDROID

Tags: android, sdk, payment-gateway, braintree

In one of my android project i have integrated com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:5.0.2 for payments which internaly uses cardinal mobile sdk 2.2.4-1 . Is there any way to upgrade only cardinal mobile sdk to 2.2.7-1 without upgrading the com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:5.0.2

we tried upgrading the com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:5.0.2 version but it asks to upgrade my project version to 31. After upgrading to 31 other dependency show errors.so want to only upgrade the cardinal sdk without upgrading the braintree